# Can VBA code be minified?

Tags: ms-access, vba, minify

In web design, it's common to minify HTML, CSS or JavaScript code to improve load times - or, sometimes, to beautify it using a tool like [Tabifier](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier) to improve readability.

As VBA code (in my case, Access VBA code) can also be beautified using the above tool, it got me wondering whether it could also be minified. I can't find any tools to do this, and a Google search for ["Can VBA code be minified?"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=can%20vba%20code%20be%20minified&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NcBPVA7BqvMHg7-C8Ak&gws_rd=ssl) turns up nothing.

Even if VBA code could be minified, would it serve any purpose?

Comment: VBA code is compiled to P-code, so minifying would do nothing other than obscure the source code.

Comment: Minification for script languages that are transferred over a network makes sense in as much as it reduces the time required for that transfer, that idea does not really apply to VBA

Comment: Would you minify C#? HTML/JS/CSS are all sent as a string. C#/VBA/VB are compiled.

Comment: VBA cant be minified like CSS/HTML/JS but there are many tips and tricks to give it a smaller foot print or run faster.  If you are looking to do that you can throw your code in code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA code can not be "Minified".  The closest equivalent is to compile the code such as saving a .mdb file as a .mde file.  Compiled access databases do run more quickly because the code is already compiled, so it doesn't have to be compiled at run-time and then executed.  This also gives the database a smaller file size, which also improves performance.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the load times in Access either have to do with server response time, network connection or poorly written code.

Server response time and network connection will not improve with changes to the code. Poorly written code minified is still poorly written code.

Most often an Access VBA solution is ran from a local desktop or a remote PC. However if an Access database were deployed to a SharePoint server then it is running is web browser like Java. However I am not sure that removing tabs, uneeded white spaces or changing line appends, `& _`, would makethings any faster even in a SharePoint environment.